# Populate parent record data on related records

Tags: related-list

Custom_object1 is parent object and custom_object2 is child object(look up relationship). When the child record is created, I want to copy parent_field1 value from parent to the child record (child_field1) based on certain criteria. I am doint this via trigger .

Now the questions is, parent_field1 is picklist on parent object, is it good to have child_field1 on child object also pick list field ? Will there be any issues if child_field1 is a text field ?

Kindly suggest whether it creates any issue if we copy parent_object field picklist field to child_object text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want the ability to have translations or not. Picklist values can be automatically translated to the user's language, but text fields can't. Aside from that, there's no real difference between using the two options. Also, you can always change the type later if you want to between picklist and text, so there's really very little to worry about in regards of which type to use.

Comment: ok, thank you for the clarification